# why are my images from ghost blog gets removed/deleted?

Tags: ghost-blog

so I have installed ghost for blogging.

But for some reason, after sometime my images from the blog gets deleted or removed or whatever. I am not sure what exactly is wrong here.

Not only from the blog's but also from the ghost settings page [image]

this is how it looks, although I had added the images earlier.

Can someone here help.

Comment: We need more details to help you better. How is your blog hosted? Possibly you have a batch script running that's deleting your images. Is it after re-deploying the blog?

In short, if you provide more details people can probably help you more :)

Comment: well, I fixed it. It was issue with the AWS S3 with paperclip. 
Thanks